# 2sxc | WYSIWYG html editor table cell width

Tags: wysiwyg, 2sxc

I wish to have the default table width display in the editor at a width that is visible as currently the default is close to zero width. The screenshot below shows the default width and below that is when you specify a set width via the properties option. Is there a way to have the table default to a certain desired width? Thx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the moment not. There are various wishes for customizing the tinymce, but before we provide specific solutions we must find a generic method for custom configuration, as we want to be sure that we don't have to support tinymce as well. So this won't be available for some time, unless someone works out a solution and contributes it.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it not possible to configure tinymce at the "normal" way with tinymce.init...?